# Table causing a stack overflow

Tags: rust, stack-overflow

I am creating a transposition table for chess in Rust. To do this, I am creating a `TranspositonEntry` which records a u64 that represents the hash of a position and a move which is really just a u16. I want to store 2^19 entries into an array. However, there is an issue. The array is causing a stack overflow.

I would think the size of the array in bytes would be 10 * 2^19, or just over 5 MB, which shouldn’t cause a stack overflow. However, I think this is incorrect, as I cannot fix the code in order to not cause a stack overflow.

A small example would be

```
struct Move {
    val : u16
}

impl Move {
    const NULL : Self = Self {val : 0};
}

struct TranspositionEntry {
    mov : Move,
    hash : u64
}

impl TranspositionEntry {
    const NULL_ENTRY: Self = Self { mov : Move::NULL, hash : 0};
}

fn main() {
    let table = [TranspositionEntry::NULL_ENTRY; 524288];
}
```

I think the table shouldn’t be large enough to cause a stack overflow, but yet it does.

Comment: I would expect the size to be 16, not 10, since the struct is probably padded to its alignment, which comes out to roughly 8.5 Mb for the whole array. How much stack memory do you have?

Comment: I would still have enough stack memory even if the array is 8.5mb.

Comment: You have to consider that some stack memory is also required for the startup of the program. If you run it in debug it'll probably need some additional stack memory (not exactly sure how much though). So it would be good if you could verify how much stack memory you have (default OS size or what you've configured it to be), because the standard is around 1Mb or so.

Comment: Why are you so sure you have enough stack memory?

Comment: Why are you storing the position as a hash? With 64 positions it would easily fit in a `u8`. Hashes are either expensive to compute, or prone to hash collisions, so probably not a good idea here.

Answer (score 5):

Default stack sizes are smaller than you think. On Windows, the stack size is only 1 MiB by default. On Linux it is typically 8 MiB, which you can check like this:

```bash
$ ulimit -s
8192
```

When you spawn a thread, you can specify a different stack size:

```rs
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    let builder = thread::Builder::new().stack_size(32 * 1024); // 32 MiB

    let handler = builder.spawn(|| {
        // this should work now
        let table = [TranspositionEntry::NULL_ENTRY; 524288];
    }).unwrap();

    handler.join().unwrap();
}
```

But in this case, the better solution is to allocate the table on the heap.

```rs
fn main() {
    let table = vec![TranspositionEntry::NULL_ENTRY; 524288];
}
```